# How can i resolve the variable i was trying to pass to a cardviewadapter that i tried to extract from sqlite cursor

Tags: android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-cardview, sqliteopenhelper

The ide tells me it cannot resolve the symbols that ive put in the ProjectsCardAdapter parameters. the symbols are variables inside a try block that contains string type from cursor

I tried to initialize the string array variables outside the try block but realized i need to getCount how many rows the cursor will have in order to initialize the string arrays.

```
public class ProjectsFragment extends Fragment {

    public ProjectsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView projectsRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_projects, container, false);

        try {
            SQLiteOpenHelper projectsDBhelper = new ProjectsDBhelper(inflater.getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = projectsDBhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("PROJECTS",
                    new String[]{"PROJ_STAGE", "PROJ_BUDGET", "PROJ_LOC", "CLIENT_NAME"}
                    , null
                    , null, null, null, null);

            int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
            String[] projStage = new String[rowCount];
            String[] projBudget = new String[rowCount];
            String[] projLoc = new String[rowCount];
            String[] clientName = new String[rowCount];
            int i = 0;
            Float floatBudget;

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                projStage[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                floatBudget = cursor.getFloat(1);
                projLoc[i] = cursor.getString(2);
                clientName[i] = cursor.getString(3);

                projBudget[i] = String.format("%,.2f", floatBudget.toString());

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            Toast exceptionToast = Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            exceptionToast.show();

        }
        //This is the ProjectsCardAdapter that couldnt resolve the symbol
        ProjectsCardAdapter projectsCardAdapter = new ProjectsCardAdapter(projStage, projBudget, projLoc, clientName);
        projectsRecycler.setAdapter(projectsCardAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        projectsRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return projectsRecycler;
    }
}
```

i wanted to test a cardview displaying a set of texts using data from SQLite but the adapter cant take the variables from cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that **projStage**, **projBudget**, **projLoc** and **clientName** are being declared in the **try** block and therefore only have scope within the the **try** block.

The following would increase the scope to be within the **onCreateView** method :-

```
public class ProjectsFragment extends Fragment {

    public ProjectsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView projectsRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_projects, container, false);
        String[] projStage;
        String[] projBudget;
        String[] projLoc;
        String[] clientName;

        try {
            SQLiteOpenHelper projectsDBhelper = new ProjectsDBhelper(inflater.getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = projectsDBhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("PROJECTS",
                    new String[]{"PROJ_STAGE", "PROJ_BUDGET", "PROJ_LOC", "CLIENT_NAME"}
                    , null
                    , null, null, null, null);

            int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
            projStage = new String[rowCount];
            projBudget = new String[rowCount];
            projLoc = new String[rowCount];
            clientName = new String[rowCount];
            int i = 0;
            Float floatBudget;

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                projStage[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                floatBudget = cursor.getFloat(1);
                projLoc[i] = cursor.getString(2);
                clientName[i] = cursor.getString(3);
                projBudget[i] = String.format("%,.2f", floatBudget.toString());

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            Toast exceptionToast = Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            exceptionToast.show();

        }
        //This is the ProjectsCardAdapter that couldnt resolve the symbol
        ProjectsCardAdapter projectsCardAdapter = new ProjectsCardAdapter(projStage, projBudget, projLoc, clientName);
        projectsRecycler.setAdapter(projectsCardAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        projectsRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return projectsRecycler;
    }
}
```

- Note, this is in-principle code. The code hasn't been tested or run and therefore may contain errors.